# Why is my fileReader wrapped in a Promise looping into infinity?

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, filereader

I'm trying to read a large file inside a serviceWorker using a fileReader. I just want to setup a simple example first but I'm stuck in an infinite loop and I don't understand why. Here is my code:

```
    .then(function(blob) {
        console.log("Let's loop out of control");

        function compressAndIndexFile(my_blob) {
          var file_reader = new FileReader(),
            chunk_size = 1024,
            offset = 0;
          return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            file_reader.onload = function (my_event) {
              // process
              offset += chunk_size
              if (offset > 2048) {
                resolve("We're done");
              }
              return loopOverBlob(offset);
            };
            file_reader.onerror = function (my_event) {
              reject(my_event);
            };

            function loopOverBlob(my_offset) {
              var slice;
              console.log("LOOPIng")
              console.log(my_offset)
              slice = blob.slice(my_offset, my_offset += chunk_size);
              return file_reader.readAsText(slice);
            }
            return loopOverBlob(offset);
          });              
        }
        return compressAndIndexFile(blob);
      })
```

I try to stop the loop after 2048 bytes and it correctly triggers after the 2nd iteration and resolves the promise. Yet the loop just continues into oblivion.

**Question:**
I'm sitting over this for a while now wondering what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone else has an idea. Thanks!

Comment: You need a return after resolve / reject

Comment: `resolve` doesn't stop your recursion

Comment: ok. Let me see if a return helps. Ha, it does. I did not know that. Thanks. Make it an answer, so I can check?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (offset > 2048) {
    resolve("We're done");
} else {
    return loopOverBlob(offset);
}
```

I've never used promises, but it looks like the recursive call is happening every time even after the resolution is fired.